# Is returning a vector slower than passing by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, stdvector

In the old days we were trained to use result parameters passed by reference in order to avoid unnecessarily copying data around.

However with smarter compilers - and particular the extensions to C++11 **is this still required**?

Specifically, is there any reason in 2018 with modern C++11/C++14 compilers to (still) use

```
void Filter(vector<CObject*> &elements, vector<CObject*> &outElements);
```

instead of simply returning the vector, i.e.

```
vector<CObject*> Filter(vector<CObject*> &elements);
```

Thanks in advance for all insights!

Comment: Copying was never required even by C++98, but RVO was and is still optional. C++17 introduces some cases when copy elision is mandatory though, but this does not include RVO. Most compiler do it this days, so I think you can rely on it, especially if it makes code cleaner.

Comment: @Ivan `C++ introduces some cases when copy elision is mandatory though, but this does not include RVO.` In what case is copy elision mandatory, besides guaranteed RVO in C++17?

Comment: imho it would make a better example if you had a `std::vector<CObject>`, because copying or not can make a big difference if `CObject`s are expensive to copy, but in this regard your two versions dont differ much

Comment: @user2079303 RVO is not guaranteed. There is a copy-elision for prvalues (pure-rvalues). Essentially it is possible to return non-copyable and non-movable objects if you do `return T()`.

Comment: @Ivan how does that differ from RVO?

Comment: @user2079303 RVO is applied to local variables (those are lvalues when you use them in return statement, not prvalue).

Comment: @Ivan That's NRVO (i.e. named RVO). There is no guaranteed NRVO indeed.

Comment: @user2079303 Irrelevant. Most of the time term copy-elision is used. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html

Comment: @Ivan RVO is indeed guaranteed since c++17. *When the nameless temporary is the argument of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value optimization".* from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: @super In my experience most developers do not distinguish RVO and NRVO and just say RVO. OPs question is an example of this - his filter function most likely needs NRVO. Document I cited above does not refer to RVO as RVO, instead it uses "guaranteed copy elision".

Comment: @Ivan Sounds about right. It is probably a good idea to start distinguishing the two now though, since c++17 makes the difference quite important in some cases.

Comment: @super Looks to me that since C++17 and lafter RVO will be deprecated and people will have to distinguish every guaranteed copy elision case separately. It is likely there will be more and more of these in the future.

Comment: @Ivan It sounds to me that you are very determined to not change the terminology you are used to, even though changes has been made to the language. Deprecated... how?

Comment: @super Not the first RVO vs NRVO debate I got into. In my experience, almost no one separate those two and term RVO is used for both cases. As for deprecation - with terms like lvalue, rvalue, prvalue, glvalue we are certainly going to the point when new cases for guaranteed copy elision will be added, using RVO imo is just misleading.

Comment: @super Your quote from cppreference belongs to _"until C++17"_ part, check again. In C++17, there is technically no RVO, since **no temporary is materialized** when returning prvalue. Therefore the effect is the same (no copy/move constructor is invoked) but accomplished via different mechanism.

Comment: @user2079303 The difference Ivan pointed out is that for RVO, you need copy/move constructor to exist. In C++17, there is different mechanism (no materialization of returned prvalue), so, no copy/move constructor is required to exist and be accessible. **Technically, there is therefore no RVO=copy elision in C++17, since there are no constructor calls to be elided.** As you asked, In C++17, copy elision is mandatory for initialization (e.g., of function parameters).

Comment: @DanielLangr You're technically correct, but that's besides the point in my opinion. Even the name of the proposal is "guaranteed copy elision ..." despite the fact that in the new rules there is no longer a copy to be elided. The new rules not only guarantee that there is no copy in practice (just like RVO), but that there is also no copy in the abstract machine model  (beyond RVO), so it would be reasonable to describe the new rules as guaranteeing RVO as that's effectively a subset of what they achieve. Thanks for pointing out the non-RVO related case of guaranteed elision of parameters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> and particular the extensions to C++11 is this still required?

No. In the best case scenario, RVO *(return value optimization)* will kick in, which will completely elide any copy/move.

In the worst case scenario, the object will be moved out of the function. Moves for `std::vector` are very cheap (comparable to just a few pointer swaps).

This is because the expression `Filter(some_input)` is an **rvalue** of type `std::vector<CObject*>`, and `std::vector`'s constructor has an overload accepting an *rvalue reference*: [see **(6)** here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: What if i am stuck with a C++ 98 compiler?

Comment: @GauravSehgal: in all seriousness, your choice is there to either rely on RVO or use an output parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> In the old days we were trained to use result parameters passed by reference in order to avoid unnecessarily copying data around.

Actually, even when one was using an old C++ compiler this was pretty poor advice: write for clarity first and efficiency second.

In particular, returning by a reference value prevents making the values in the caller `const` (which improves clarity *and* provides other optimization opportunity).

Of course, if profiling shows this was a performance bottleneck, then one had to make the necessary changes.  With RVO and NRVO (which are now pretty common), and move semantics as a back-up it is now very unlikely to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Particularly true when the example is a vector of pointers - copying this is going to be fast; so no need to worry about the efficiency at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you return value from a function, compiler applies Return Value Optimization to avoid copying. 
So, both cases will be similar.
You can read more [there](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/RVO_V_S_std_move?lang=en).

Comment: Whether the compiler applies RVO depends on things.